# Inserting new id from sequence into table column id and insert that same id to another table without dual table

Tags: plsql

I have a table:

```sql
create table osoba (osoba_id number,
                    ime_osobe varchar2(200),
                    prezime_osobe varchar2(200),
                    kartica_id number)

create table kartica (kartica_id number,
                      dozvoljen_ulaz_id number)
```

I need to make procedure that

- Inserts data into table `osoba`.
- Checks if there is data in table `kartica` column `kartica_id`.

  - If there is, add that id to column `kartica_id` in table `osoba`.
  - If there isn't, then add `kartica_id` in `kartica` table by sequence I have created and then add that newly created `kartica.kartica_id` to `kartica_id` in table `osoba`.

`Kartica_id` in `kartica` and `kartica_id` in `osoba` must be unique and only one `kartica_id` for one record in `osoba` for that exact record (person added).

If there is already a `kartica_id` added to `osoba.kartica_id` of the same value then throw error message `'Kartica_id already exists. No same values allowed.'` and insert next new `kartica_id` value to `kartica` table and pass that value to `kartica_id` in table `osoba`.

I'm new to pl/sql so this is where I got so far:

```sql
create or replace procedure insertOsoba
   ( o_osoba_id in osoba.osoba_id%type default generate_id.nextval,
     o_ime_osobe in osoba.ime_osobe%type,
     o_prezime_osobe in osoba.prezime_osobe%type,
     o_kartica_id in kartica.kartica_id%type default null --must be optional
   )
is
begin
      insert into osoba (osoba_id,ime_osobe,prezime_osobe,kartica_id)
      values (o_osoba_id,o_ime_osobe,o_prezime_osobe,o_kartica_id);
end insertosoba;
```

Comment: For me it is very difficult to read and understand your question.
But first of all you must check (with a cursor) if a record in tabel kartica with the given value of parameter o_kartica_id exists.

If the record exists then show the message.
If the record does not exists then first create a record into table kartica; using a unique value for osoba (sequence??). And then insert a new record into tabel osoba using the value of kartica_id and other input parameters of the procedure.

What must happen if the value of parameter o_kartica_id is null? Nothing or also an insert in both tables?

Comment: If  the value of parameter o_kartica_id is null then insert new value in table kartica on kartica_id and pass that value to kartica_id in osoba table.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make another `insert` into a second table and reuse the same sequence number? There are several ways to do that (and none of them involve `dual`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting solution where I use `kartica_seq` as a sequence for `kartica_id`. Please replace it with your sequence name or create sequence if it not exist.

`create sequence kartica_seq start with 1 increment by 1;`

```
create or replace procedure insertOsoba
   ( o_osoba_id in osoba.osoba_id%type default generate_id.nextval,
     o_ime_osobe in osoba.ime_osobe%type,
     o_prezime_osobe in osoba.prezime_osobe%type,
     o_kartica_id in kartica.kartica_id%type default null --must be optional
   )
is
cnt number;
cnt2 number;
begin
      select count(*) into cnt from osoba where kartica_id = o_kartica_id;
      select count(*) into cnt2 from kartica where kartica_id = o_kartica_id;
      if(cnt = 0) then
        --there is no person with such kartica and user passed existing kartica_id
        if(o_kartica_id is not null and cnt2 > 0) then
          insert into osoba (osoba_id,ime_osobe,prezime_osobe,kartica_id)
          values (o_osoba_id,o_ime_osobe,o_prezime_osobe,o_kartica_id);
        --there is no person with such kartica but we need to create one entry using sequence
        else
          insert into kartica (kartica_id) values (kartica_seq.nextval);
          insert into osoba (osoba_id,ime_osobe,prezime_osobe,kartica_id)
          values (o_osoba_id,o_ime_osobe,o_prezime_osobe,kartica_seq.currval);
        end if;
      end if;
      --there is person with such kartica
      if(cnt > 0) then
        dbms_output.put_line('Kartica_id already exists. No same values allowed.'); --or raise an exception here
      end if;
      commit;
end insertosoba;
```

Comment: There are errors in line 15 and 18 with INSERT statement  
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" when expecting one of the following:
          * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then
          <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
          like4 likec between overlaps || multiset year day member
Line: 15
Text: insert into osoba (osoba_id,ime_osobe,prezime_osobe,kartica_id)

Comment: Need to put THEN after second if and variable cntk rename to cnt2

Comment: @Rinma33 yes you're right. There was also t missing in `dbms_output` I posted first then tested. Should probably test first ;)

Comment: Thanks allot @Kacper! That helped and working fine :)